# Gaussian mixture model using sklean to fit on data

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian

I am trying to fit gaussians on a given dataset.
Here is an example dataset.

[image]

I would like to find two reasonable gaussian to fit them.
Thus, I wrote the following code to use GMM.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from scipy.stats import norm
 
def main():
    x = np.arange(-28,28,2)
    y = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,4,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,0,0,1])
    plt.plot(x,y,'ro')
    plt.savefig("tmp.png")
    plt.clf()    
    data = np.stack( (x,y), axis=-1)
    print(data)  
    gmm = GaussianMixture(
            n_components=2,
            covariance_type='spherical',
            init_params='random',
            ).fit(data.reshape(-1,1))
    weights = gmm.weights_
    means = gmm.means_
    cov = gmm.covariances_
    
    print(weights)
    print(means)
    print(cov)
    
    gd0 = weights[0] * norm.pdf(x, means[0][0], np.sqrt(cov[0]))
    gd1 = weights[1] * norm.pdf(x, means[1][0], np.sqrt(cov[1]))
    plt.plot(x, gd0)
    plt.plot(x, gd1)
    plt.savefig("tmp2.png")    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then, I get the result.
But it seems strange. I expected the peaks of Gaussians appeared around -15 and +15.
Where did I make a mistake?

weights

> [0.52290556 0.47709444]

means

> [[-0.78959748]
> [ 1.68885233]]

cov

> [250.29609772 3.07633333]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to fit the data? 'Cause it looks like you might be trying to fit the distribution-plot instead...

Comment: Yes. I want to fit the Gaussians on the date.

Comment: Right, but that's not the *data* you're trying to fit. that's a presentation of an approximation of the _distribution_ you'd like to approximate...

Comment: Thank you. I did not know the correct definition of data.